# How to add integer to 2-D array items

Tags: javascript, arrays

So lets say I have a log in google's console like this

```
[[296,279],[304,280],[308,280],[312,280]]
```

from my script here below

```
evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
var obj = JSON.parse(e.data);
var line = JSON.stringify(obj.line)
var size = JSON.stringify(obj.lineWidth)
var color = JSON.stringify(obj.lineColor) // Not needed, but defined anyways.
var chat = JSON.stringify(obj.msg)

if (obj.ident === "") //mee
{
$.post("/draw.php?ing=_index", {
            l: (line),
            w : parseInt(obj.lineWidth) + 2,
            c: ("ffffff"),
            o: ("100"),
            f: ("1"),
            _: ("false")
 })
 console.log(line) //Logs the line. (Example in question.)
```

How could I add a value of 20 to each item in the array when it logs.
So it will log something like this

```
[[316,299],[324,300],[328,300],[332,300]]
```

and not like this (The original.)

```
[[296,279],[304,280],[308,280],[312,280]]
```

Comment: Do you want to override `console.log` to alter all the arrays? or just create a function that alters the array and the prints it?

Comment: If it can add 20 to each one. It will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print the array with altered data but without altering the original you probably want to use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to copy the array.

`JSON.stringify` also accepts a second parameter that allows you to edit the values while the object is being stringified.

```js
var original = [
  [296, 279],
  [304, 280],
  [308, 280],
  [312, 280],
  [[58, 60], [75, 84]],
  4,
  [[5, 9], [[0], [-3]], 8]
];

var json = JSON.stringify(original, function(key, value) {
  return typeof value === "number" ? value + 20 : value;
});
console.log(json);
console.log(JSON.parse(json));
```

This will work, regardless of how many dimensions the array has (and is ES5 compatible).

Comment: Elegant but probably worst solution, jsonifying just to parse the number back and stringify it again

Comment: Why regex ? and now the value is string not the array anymore ?

Comment: The OP did not ask for no alteration. But performance-wise cloning using a deep clone function should be faster than stringifying. I did give you credit for the idea though

Comment: In the same thread you find the link to a benchmark and see that it is the slowest option: http://jsben.ch/bWfk9. And you are converting parts of it back to a number, in the replace lambda. The result is than converted back to string

Comment: Yours works fine, problem is it adds " before and after it logs.

Comment: Anyway to remove the " when it logs? Then I'll be on my way and accept.

Comment: This is how I need it to log in console [[296,279],[304,280],[308,280],[312,280]]
This is how it logged with your script "[[296,279],[304,280],[308,280],[312,280]]
"

Comment: That is because it is a string. Use one of the other answers

Comment: See how I've got a post JQuery post request. I'm trying to basically use your script as a variable where "l: (line)" is.

Comment: If it can remove the " somehow I would be finished. That's all I need.

Comment: It works fine adding the 20 to the values. It just adds " to the log now.

Comment: Oh sorry. I was lagging or something. Didn't see your that reply.

Comment: @MofX Parsing and stringify is 40% slower, but this will work regardless of the depth of the object, unlike the `map` option that should be changed to a recursion to work. It's also ES5 compatible and doesn't require any libraries.

Comment: @Sparklestheunicorn Updated the answer. This will now work regardless of the depth (`[1,2]`, `[[1,2]]`, `[[[1,2]]]` will all work)

Comment: @Sparklestheunicorn Glad that worked for you, I would appreciate if you could remove any comments you've to the answer that you deem unnecessary, to keep things clean.

Answer (score 4):

Use `map`:

```js
const arr = [
  [296, 279],
  [304, 280],
  [308, 280],
  [312, 280]
];

const res = arr.map(e => e.map(f => f + 20));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: auto;
}
```

Comment: Just observe that arrow functions were not implemented until ES6, so some browsers might struggle with this. Looking at you IE

Comment: Yes, I know @Ozgar, but that's a fairly simple problem to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.
Here we provide a function which will be executed with each element of the array. Which in your case will be another `map` function.

```js
const line = [[296, 279],[304, 280],[308, 280],[312, 280]]

const out = line.map(arr => arr.map(x => x + 20))
console.log(out)
```

Comment: How is this different than Jack Bashford's answer?

Comment: There was no answer. When I had started typing the code.

Comment: I'm trying to add a variable where line is. So something like ``const data = line`` Cause` the variable ''line'' logs the original array. I need it to read from the variable.

Comment: So when I try to replace "[[296, 279],[304, 280],[308, 280],[312, 280]]" with "line" I get a error in console. Saying something about map.

Comment: what is the issue?